# .net publish applicationUrl issues (ubuntu vm)

Tags: .net, ubuntu, nginx, publish, loopback

i have some problems trying to publish an .net core webapi on ubuntuServer on local VM

my problem is, when i publish my webapi application the applicationUrl dont change for the correct address, see the images below.

my steps,

i have create a new webapi (dotnet new webapi)
[webapi Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8h79.png)

[lauchSettings.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ht3vb.png) the lauchSettings of the project folder

[/var/www/minhaapi <- publish directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVfJL.png)
my published directory

[dotnet minhaapi.dll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vc807.png) tying run the publishied
so i need the listening on http://0.0.0.0:5000 and 5001, because the localhost block my external acess with loopback

[ss -nltup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXdcX.png)
the bind address. on 127.0.0.1 not onn 0.0.0.0

[dotnet run on webapi project folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XSzV.png)
when i try to dotnet run on project folder i got the corretcly addres, and now i can acess out my vm, but when i try run on published i get the localhost instead of 0.0.0.0,

https://postimg.cc/qgDZhNH6

the command to publish dotnet publish -o /var/www/minhaapi
thx for help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already solved the problem,

on my service on /etc/systemd/system/minhaapi.service, i add this line
`Environment=ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://0.0.0.0:5000`

and work correctly !